# Class Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\AbstractResource does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.3

/var/www/html/magento23# php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 1 min 282.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 35:

Class Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\AbstractResource does not exist

In ClassReader.php line 29:

Class Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\AbstractResource does not exist

setup:di:compile

Comment: Check if file exist or not - If not then just remove everything from vendor folder and run composer to re-create vendor file or you can download and upload it manually

Answer (score 0):

> Removed `var/generation` folder then run magento `setup:di:compile`
> which generated all necessary classes.

Comment: yes I did, but again getting same error..!